# Is it possible to display Flash movies inside a Flex application and interact with them?

Tags: apache-flex, flash

Since I've never done this and the google results are quite random, I ask here: Is it possible to display Flash movies inside a Flex application and interact with them?

The scenario is as follows:

- I'm developing a new application in flex
- Another, already completed application is given to me as SWF (or perhaps SWC, don't know any details yet)
- I have to insert this second application inside in my Flex application, which should be no problem afair
- I have to interact with this application: send and retrieve data. Don't know any further details here, too.

Will this be possible? Or is Flex only capable of displaying the SWF without the possibility to interact with it? I hope you can understand, what I want (have to...) do.

Flex Version will be the current nightly of version 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can easy loading an external swf into your Flex application using the standard [SWFLoader component](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=controls_15.html) ([reference here](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/controls/SWFLoader.html)).

For the interaction you can pass data to your swf when you load it ([see this for example](http://www.asyncria.com/node/10)) or you can pass value at runtime, i've never tried but [reading this](http://learn.adobe.com/wiki/display/Flex/Local+Connections) it seems that Local connections works also with loaded movies.

Comment: If the loaded clip is Actionscript 3 (AVM2) then you can call functions and interact directly with the clip. You only need to use `LocalConnection` if the clip is Actionscript 1/2 (AVM1). Info here: http://www.kirupa.com/forum/showthread.php?p=1964550